# Eclipse cannot remove folder: Permission denied error

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, permissions

I am trying to build PostgreSQL in Eclipse (helios) in Ubuntu.
I followed the instructions in https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Working_with_Eclipse

I got "All of PostgreSQL successfully made, Ready to install" message when I build the code.
However, when I try to make target and build it, it gives following error.

```
make install 
make -C src install
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/ubuntu/git/postgresql2/src'
make -C common install
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/ubuntu/git/postgresql2/src/common'
make -C ../backend submake-errcodes
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/ubuntu/git/postgresql2/src/backend'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `submake-errcodes'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/ubuntu/git/postgresql2/src/backend'
/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/pgsql/lib'
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644  libpgcommon.a '/usr/local/pgsql/lib/libpgcommon.a'
/usr/bin/install: cannot remove `/usr/local/pgsql/lib/libpgcommon.a': Permission denied
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/ubuntu/git/postgresql2/src/common'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ubuntu/git/postgresql2/src'
make[2]: *** [install] Error 1
make[1]: *** [install-common-recurse] Error 2
make: *** [install-src-recurse] Error 2
```

There is a permission error. How can I solve it?

Comment: a) that's not a folder, it's a file and b) you probably don't have the correct permissions on the containing folder. Try deleting the file from the command line and see if that gives the same error

Comment: it works when I run "sudo make install" however, it still gives error in eclipse when i try to build target

Comment: So yolu don't have permisson when running Eclipse as non-root. Not sure what you're expecting to happen here.

Comment: @halilenver - did you ever solve this problem?  If so, would you mind sharing how?